# Wifi very slow ONLY on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless

It seems that **one particular** Wifi network is very slow **only** on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 machine. The same network is totally fine when I use MacOS or Windows 10. My Ubuntu machine also has no problems when I connect to a different Wifi network or personal hotspot so my guess is that somehow Ubuntu is having an issue with this one particular Wifi network.

The same web page in Mac / Windows takes a second to load whilst on Ubuntu it takes around anything from 5-15 seconds. The loading times on Ubuntu are very inconsistent - sometimes it's totally fine but usually much slower.

I was also having this issue with 16.04 and ended up upgrading to 18.04.2 in the hopes of fixing it. That didn't work so I resorted to completely reinstalling 18.04.2 from scratch(!) and still no luck. I thought I'd switch back to Linux after using MacOS for a while but immediately I get stumped with this blocker :(

I'm not a Linux wiz so I'm not too sure how to troubleshoot this and what information would be useful for debugging?

#### sudo lshw -class network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 48:ba:4e:b3:ed:f9
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4104000-a4104fff memory:a4100000-a4103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: f8:94:c2:bb:66:60
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-25-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.68 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:a4000000-a4001fff
```

Comment: @Coditoergosum Not really an option I'm afraid. In my new spirit of open source, I want to start using Firefox!

Comment: TKIP encryption might be used on the one problem network